# мне и надо чтоб при условие порт атмега 8 стал выходом с нулём а если условия нет то вход с подтянутом резистором

Tags: avr

пишу вот так

```
if(PIND & (1<<PIND1)){DDRC |=   (1 << PC0);PORTC &= ~ (1 << PC0);}
else {DDRC &= ~ (1 << PC0);PORTC |=   (1 << PC0);}
```

не работает!

выход как то мерцает не туда не сюда нормальный выход непреврощаеться в протеусе даже а когда сделал на микроконтролере тоже самое
кто может помочь?